# Why EJB session bean has "session" in name?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-7

I use EJB, I like it but can't understand why they are called "session beans". Does it use Http Session in some way? It doesn't make sense to me. If I have long session-timeout in web.xml will it affect EJB?

Comment: No, it doesn't have anything to do with the HTTP session. It doesn't have anything to do with actual beans either, BTW :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 types of EJBs: session, message-driven, and entity (deprecated in favor of JPA).

They are called session beans because they perform business logic for a client's working session, as opposed to the work being persistent or triggered by a message.  The name does not come from any session object in particular.

The name session is mainly to highlight the type of logic that should be performed by this bean type.

Comment: And just to spice things up a little more. There are stateless and stateful session beans :)